# Which XML library is used for PyBrain?

Tags: python, xml, pybrain

I'm using PyBrain in a project over Windows 7 and I've had not problem with this library until I had to write the trained network to a XML file.

I tried this "from pybrain.tools.xml.networkwriter import NetworkWriter" but I got an importation error.

Can anyone tell me if there's a requirement to get this job done?

I tried installing the library called "lxml", because I have it installed on my linux pc, but it doesn't seem to work along side with pybrain.

Answer (score 0):

PyBrain declares in it's `setup.py` only one required package `scipy`.

Scipy is a bit complex stuff and it is best installed from binaries (at least on Windows). So if you manage installing scipy, you shall make PyBrain running.

Comment: Sorry.I was using the last version and didn't notice that there was some changes on the pybrain code. It's running well right now.